# How to parse json string in python?

Tags: python, json

Below code is running fine.

```
 import json
 json_data = '{"Detail":" Rs. 2000 Topup Rs.1779.99 Talktime","Amount":"2000","Validity":"Unlimited"}'
        json_parsed = json.loads(json_data)
        print(json_parsed['Detail'])
        print(json_parsed['Amount'])
        print(json_parsed['Validity'])
```

How to parse below json string? and How to display all values also?

```
json_data = '[{"Detail":" Rs. 2000 Topup Rs.1779.99 Talktime","Amount":"2000","Validity":"Unlimited"},{"Detail":" Rs. 1900 Topup Rs.1690.99 Talktime","Amount":"1900","Validity":"Unlimited"}]'
```

Please help me.

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing? Did you try your code against the json string?

Comment: The only difference is that the second string is an array of objects - so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I don't how to parse this string *[{"Detail":" Rs. 2000 Topup Rs.1779.99 Talktime","Amount":"2000","Validity":"Unlimited"},{"Detail":" Rs. 1900 Topup Rs.1690.99 Talktime","Amount":"1900","Validity":"Unlimited"}]*

Comment: why giving down votes to my question? Don't know how to do that because of that only raised question. Actually i am very new to python. After i done lot of R&D only i got the first answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This json string is an array of objects, as opposed to a  single object.

You'd parse it the same way with the json module, however instead of getting a single dictionary you would get a list of dictionaries.

you'd be able to display as so:

```
import json

json_data = '[{"Detail":" Rs. 2000 Topup Rs.1779.99 Talktime","Amount":"2000","Validity":"Unlimited"},{"Detail":" Rs. 1900 Topup Rs.1690.99 Talktime","Amount":"1900","Validity":"Unlimited"}]'

# convert to python data structure
d_list = json.loads(json_data)

# loop through the list
for d in d_list:
    # use get for safety
    print d.get('Detail')
    print d.get('Amount')
```

Regardless of the parsing language, python, javascript, php and so on, any json string or subset of a json string that has objects wrapped in [brackets] will be an array, and will need to be handled in a  similar (language specific) fashion.